# Django Migrations Issue that cause my django admin panel to error out

Tags: python, django, database, django-migrations

I am working on a backend for some web app Using **Django** and it is **working 100% fine on my local machine**, However; I had to deploy on **digital ocean** apps and i followed a guide and it went perfectly well but when i try to open the admin panel and access some of my tables i get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvg79.jpg). Below is a small log portion related to error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column myapi_schedule.Start_Time does not exist
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-12 21:51:50] LINE 1: ...."Start_Date", "myapi_schedule"."Products_Array", "myapi_sch...
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-12 21:51:50]                                                              ^
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-12 21:51:50] HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "myapi_schedule.Start_Date".
```

Edit: My Models

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name_count=models.TextField()
    makespan=models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    Interrupt_Flag=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank = True)
    Interrupt_Type=models.CharField(default="none",max_length=200,blank = True)
    Original_Schedule_Id=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    Hold_Duration=models.FloatField(default=0,blank = True,null=True)
    Hold_Index=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank = True,null=True)
    Start_Date=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Products_Array=models.TextField(blank=True)
    Start_Time=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True,null=True)
    Favorite=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Run_Type=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True)
    Cost=models.FloatField(default=0,blank = True,null=True)

class Machine(models.Model):
    """Machines Table with user relation and a name and status with future upgrade for metrics and sensor readings"""

    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Machine_Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Machine_Status=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    MachineSet=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ImageUrl=models.TextField(blank=True)



class UserAttribute(models.Model):
    Parent_User_Id=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Company_Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)





class Product(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Product_Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    list_mach=models.TextField()
    list_durat=models.TextField()
    list_dep=models.TextField()
```

Show migrations output:

```
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
authtoken
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20160226_1747
 [X] 0003_tokenproxy
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the column `myapi_schedule.Start_Time` is missing. Perhaps you need to run ‘makemigrations‘ locally, check in the new migration files, deploy them to production and then run `migrate`. It’s hard to give a more specific answer unless you show your models, migrations, and the output of `manage.pay showmigrations` In production.

Comment: @Alasdair I did run these commands and nothing new. I updated the Question with what you asked.

Comment: @Alasdair is there a way i can just reset all migrations and get a fresh start and start from my current point as i am 100% sure it is a migrations issue and the code runs perfectly locally but on the server its messed up.

Comment: I expected to see migrations for your `myapi` app in the `showmigrations` output

Comment: If there isn’t any important data in your production database, you could drop the database and then run migrate again. The instructions for dropping the database depend on which database you are using (e.g. SQLite/MySQL.

Comment: If there isn’t any important data in your local database, you could drop that, remove any migrations from `myapi`, and then run `python manage.py makemigrations myapi`. Make sure you check migrations into your git repo, so that you are running the same migrations in all environments.

Comment: @Alasdair Im using a postgresql Database. And okay i will try now and update you.

Comment: @Alasdair same thing errors out the same way.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t have any other suggestions. I can’t see your migrations that are creating the `myapi_schedule` table, so I can’t tell why it’s being created incorrectly in your other environment.

Comment: @Alasdair ty for trying <3